# How to make circular segment deliberately in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

If I draw curve using the pencil tool, some pairs of nodes appear to be constrained as if connected by a circular curve. Such pairs of nodes are then accompanied by "center marks". When I drag this center mark, the curve radius is adjusted, making bezier handles change:

[image]

Is it possible to constrain two nodes this way deliberately, like the following two nodes, which don't have center indicator:

[image]

---

Here is an example where I want to add a control point

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 different things going on with this-

First is using the Corner Widget (with the White arrow Tool)  to adjust the corner radius of Corner or Cusp Anchor Points. *This will only work on Corner Points* (that have no Bezier handles) or *Cusp Points* (anchors that have non- opposing Bezier handles which you adjust individually). This is accessed through View> Show Corner Widgets.

The second is if you have *Smooth Points* (anchor points that have opposing Bezier Handles that move together) the corner widget is not available. You can use the Anchor Point Tool (nested with the Pen Tool typically) to adjust curvature of a segment which will constrain the Bezier handles of the adjacent anchor points. You will probably still need some direct adjustment of the handles to make that work OK.

Here I am using the Pen Tool rather than the Pencil Tool to better control anchor point placement:

[image]

Comment: I think the primary issue may be the OP's use of the Pencil Tool. That's not for precision.

Comment: Thanks. But see my update on your example please. I want the thing, which is marked by arrow, to appear. I already have two points and want to convert edge between them into arc. Is it possible?

Comment: This is not possible the way you have things constructed. The Corner Widget (what you are wanting to see between those 2 points) is only available using the Direct Selection Tool on a Corner Anchor or on a Cusp Anchor. In your second example the only way to adjust the curvature between those 2 highlighted anchors is with the bezier handles.